# How to simulate spin-1 systems with qiskit or on the IBMQ platform?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state

I am wondering how to simulate spin-1 systems with qiskit or on the IBMQ
platform? I want to initialize a qudit (a spin-1 system), and then define the usual operations (such as Sx, Sy, and Sz) on the system. If you have any experience with this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is access higher energy levels on a real backend with Qiskit Pulse as described in their [tutorial](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/quantum-hardware-pulses/accessing-higher-energy-states-with-qiskit-pulse).

You can excite for example from the ground state $| 0 \rangle$ to the first excitation $|1 \rangle$ with an $\pi$-pulse and use another $\pi$-pulse with the frequency that matches the 1 -> 2 transition to reach $| 2 \rangle$. Then you can map:

$|0 \rangle \mapsto | s=1, m_s= -1 \rangle$

$|1 \rangle \mapsto | s=1, m_s = 0 \rangle$

$|2 \rangle \mapsto | s=1, m_s = +1 \rangle.$

Of course the downside is that in practice the measured signal for the excitations do overlap.[image: These are the results that I obtained with that method using IBM Q Ehningen (not a public backend).]

Another possibility for theoretical computations with Qiskit is to use the density matrices from [Qiskit Quantum Info](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/quantum_info.html) by mapping the 2-qubit states:

$|00 \rangle \mapsto |s = 1, m_s = -1 \rangle$

$|01 \rangle \mapsto |s = 1, m_s = 0 \rangle$

$|10 \rangle \mapsto |s = 1, m_s = +1 \rangle$

and drop $|11 \rangle$. The drop corresponds to removing the last row and column of the density matrix.